# Updating component state upon error catching in async operation

Tags: reactjs

I am fairly new to React, and am building a signup/login feature tied to a backend JSON api.
I have a signup form component that makes an API call when the submit button is pressed. The API call is processed by an authentication service.
I am looking to update the state of the initial component in case of a failure response from the API, and can't seem to figure out how to that, since once in the catch block I don't have access to the component's state. Here is the code for the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Auth from '../services/AuthService';
import {ButtonInput, Panel} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Form, ValidatedInput} from 'react-bootstrap-validation';
import {Radio, RadioGroup} from 'react-bootstrap-validation';
import Loader from 'react-loader-advanced';



export default class Signup extends React.Component {


    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            loader: false
        };
    }


    _handleValidSubmit(values) {

        this.setState({loader: true});
        Auth.signup(values.email, values.password, values.firstName, values.lastName)
            .catch(function (err) {

                var response=  JSON.parse(err.response);
                var errors = response.error;
                var errorText = '';
                for (var k in errors){
                    if (errors.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                        errorText = errorText + errors[k] + '\n';
                    }
                }
                alert(errorText);
                return false;
            });




    }

    _handleInvalidSubmit(errors, values) {
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <Panel>
                <Form onValidSubmit={this._handleValidSubmit.bind(this)}
                      onInvalidSubmit={this._handleInvalidSubmit.bind(this)}>


                    <ValidatedInput
                        type='email'
                        name='email'
                        label='Email'

                        errorHelp={{
                        required: 'Please enter your email',
                        isEmail: 'Please enter a valid email'
                    }}/>

                    <ValidatedInput
                        type='password'
                        name='password'
                        label='Password'

                        validate='required,isLength:6:60'
                        errorHelp={{
                        required: 'Please specify a password',
                        isLength: 'Password must be at least 6 characters'
                    }}/>

                    <ValidatedInput
                        type='text'
                        name='firstName'
                        label='First Name'
                        validate='required,isAlpha,isLength:2:200'
                        errorHelp={{
                        required: 'Please enter your first name',
                        isAlpha: 'Please enter a valid first name',
                        isLength: 'Please enter a valid first name'

                    }}/>

                    <ValidatedInput
                        type='text'
                        name='lastName'
                        label='Last Name'
                        validate='required,isAlpha,isLength:2:200'
                        errorHelp={{
                        required: 'Please enter your last name',
                        isAlpha: 'Please enter a valid last name',
                        isLength: 'Please enter a valid last name'
                    }}/>
                    <Loader show={this.state.loader} message={'loading'}>
                        <ButtonInput
                            type='submit'
                            bsSize='large'
                            bsStyle='primary'
                            value='Register'
                        />
                    </Loader>

                </Form>
            </Panel>
        )
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is add something like `this.setState({loader: false});`in the catch block of _handleInvalidSubmit in order to cancel the loader and re render the component - but once within the catch block the callback doesn't have access to the component context.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: why not just bind your catch function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Javascript closures to help yourself out here, and do something like:

```
_handleValidSubmit(values) {

    this.setState({loader: true});
    var that = this;
    Auth.signup(values.email, values.password, values.firstName, values.lastName)
        .catch(function (err) {
            that.setState({loader: false});
            var response=  JSON.parse(err.response);
            var errors = response.error;
            var errorText = '';
            for (var k in errors){
                if (errors.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                    errorText = errorText + errors[k] + '\n';
                }
            }
            alert(errorText);
            return false;
        });
}
```

it's a pretty standard trick in JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a transpiler, you can use an anonymous function in the catch handler.

```
...catch(err=>{this.setState( {loader: false})});
```